# Solr phrase query ignoring stopwords

Tags: solr

i am playing with Apache Solr to create search capabilities for a web site.
I setup the text fields with the default type text_it, which is defined in managed-schema as follow:

```
<fieldType name="text_it" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_it.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_it.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.ItalianLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I have a large database of delicatessen products. Every Product has a product type and the name of the producer. For example:

- product-type: Prosciutto **di** Parma, producer-name: company abc
- product-type: Brunello **di** Montalcino, producer-name: winemaker x
- product-type: Brunello **di** Montalcino, producer-name: winemaker y
- product-type: Miele **di** Montalcino, producer-name: company alpha
- product-type: Lardo **di** Colonnata, producer-name: company beta
- ... and many more

Note that the word **di** is classified as an italian stopword in the file stopwords_it.txt.

Give the records above, if i query for **brunello di montalcino** without specifying the field name, i get all the records with the word **di** inside the field product-type. Unfortunately the results are a large numebr and most of them are totally unrelated to the user query. Clearly this is not what i want.

Ideally i would like to get only the 2 records with **brunello di montalcino**. It is ok to get also the record with **miele di montalcino**

What solr setup will anable me to achieve this?

Thanks

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you design your schema ( as you have done) with the correct usage of the stopword and contraction files the following step is to design your solrconfig.xml and specifically the request handler that is going to process your request.
In there you can configure the query parser with the default field and potentially advance configurations ( such as different fields to be involved, different boost ect ect) [1]

After you properly configured the request handler you can run a phrase query ( quotes are important) :
"brunello di montalcino"

In case you want a little bit more flexibility you can play with your relevancy and specify a  ( minimum match) factor to obtain results such the one you mentioned ( with miele di Montalcino)

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Syntax+and+Parsing

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think is possible to avoid the double quotes in the query? I also would like to handle query like -->miele brunello<-- which with doble quotes wont match.

Comment: You can play with dismax and edismax mm parameter, and phrase boosting in the request handler.
You can play with phrase slops ( which means a tolerance in distance between terms for the phrase to match).
Take a look to dismax and edismax detailed pages!